# Custom validator in prop types not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

## Custom validators not working in prop-types

I am publishing a react component to npm, and I am using prop-types to validate the props of my component. My props are all optional, but if a certain prop is enabled, the other one becomes required. I am trying to achieve this using the custom validator (https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html), but it's not working as expected.

### What I tried

```
Component.propTypes = {
    interactive: PropTypes.boolean,
    handlRate: function (props, propName) {
        if (props['interactive'] === true && typeof(props[propName]) !== 'function') 
            return new Error("Please provide a handleRate function!");
        if (!!props[propName] && typeof(props[propName]) !== 'function')
            return new Error("handleRate should be a function!");
    },
}
```

Comment: my bad, it was just a typo. it should be handleRate, not handlRate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an almost an hour of scratching my head, it was just a typo. It shouldn't be **handlRate**, but **handleRate**. Always double check your code!